# How to display <md-progress-linear md-mode="indeterminate"> on click button?

Tags: angularjs

I am uploading a file for that I have to display progress bar using  but it should be after clicking on Upload button
        '
          
         Start Upload 
        
         
    '

Comment: Please provide code, and any steps you have so far tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @Dan I have tried above

Comment: You could use `ng-show="uploading"` on the md-dialog-content and inside the `importSite` function begin with `$scope.uploading = true`, and with `$scope.uploading = false`.

Comment: Note as well that if `md-mode` is set to a non-valid value, then the `md-progress-linear` will automatically get the `.ng-hide` class, setting display to none. So you could also make the mode a scope value, and set it to 'indeterminate' during upload.

Comment: <md-dialog-actions  ng-show="uploading" style="height: 75px;">
    <md-button   ng-disabled="disableUploadButton" data-ng-click="importSite(myFile)" class="md-primary md-raised">Start Upload </md-button>
    <md-progress-linear md-mode="indeterminate"  valude=" " style="left:0px;position:absolute;"></md-progress-linear> 
      </md-dialog-actions>

Comment: @Dan I have done this but this time uploading button is not is not visible

Comment: Put the `ng-show` on `md-progress-linear`, not on the `md-dialog-actions`. After all that's what you want to conditionally show, right?

Comment: Please accept the answer below if you feel this question has been answered :).

Comment: @Dan thank you it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<md-dialog-actions style="height: 75px;"> 
  <md-button ng-disabled="disableUploadButton" 
             data-ng-click="importSite(myFile)" 
             class="md-primary md-raised">Start Upload 
  </md-button> 
  <md-progress-linear ng-show="uploading" 
                      md-mode="indeterminate" 
                      style="left:0px;position:absolute;">
  </md-progress-linear> 
</md-dialog-actions>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.uploading = false;

$scope.importSite = function(myFile){
  $scope.uploading = true;
  // other code
  $scope.uploading = false;
}
```